# BIND logging - general vs. unmatched

Tags: logging, bind

The BIND9 *Administrator's reference manual* states that the `general` category is "the catch-all; many things still aren't classified into categories, and they all end up here."

On the other hand, the `unmatched` category is for "messages that **named** was unable to determine the class of or for which there was no matching `view`. A one line summary is also logged to the `client` category. This category is best sent to a file or *stderr*, by default it is sent to the `null` channel."

Thus, messages that aren't classified into a category end up in the `general` category. But, as that means **named** was unable to determine the class, it also falls into the `unmatched` category?